# 0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1360:8001::17)]

Tags: networking, apt, updates

When I run `sudo apt-get update`, it gets stuck at `Connecting to ...`

```
$ sudo apt-get update
0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1360:8001::17)]
```

That's all the command outputs. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the computer believes it has IPv6-connectivity, whilst it in fact does not have it. This can be verified by trying the command 
`ping6 www.google.com`.

You can disable IPv6 on Ubuntu, by running the following command. To enable IPv6 again,simply do `rm /etc/sysctl.d/99-disable-ipv6.conf`

```
echo "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1" | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/99-disable-ipv6.conf
```

You can also create this file, using a text editor, and pasting the content

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Then run `sudo service procps reload` to reload.

Comment: It works temporarily when i run the commands but does the same thing after i reboot. So i added the script and now i'm getting this. Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hvr/ghc/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1562::19)]^C

Comment: Rebooted it today seem to be working. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! Works great!

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue, but was solved instantly by following the steps below:

a) open terminal and run the command
   `sudo nano /etc/gai.conf`

b) Scroll down in the file gai.conf using the arrow keys and remove the comment(#) from the line:   `#precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100`

Save the file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and then exit by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Comment: Although not required, it helps sometimes to explain why this works:  Your network is not responding well to IPV6 addresses (my ISP does not use IPV6 at all, and I'm near Seattle).  This line gives precedence to IPV4 addresses in GetAdrressInfo.