# Python 3.8 + Pip on WSL

Tags: python, python3, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pip

I've being looking around on the internet and either nobody else has this problem, or nobody else can solve it. I used the deadsnake repository to use Python 3.8, which seems to work, but when I try to get pip it starts complaining about not having distutils.cmd. This is WSL Ubuntu 22.04. There shouldn't be a *.cmd anything.

Online everybody who claims to know tells me use apt install python3-pip. This just installs python3.10 even though the article was about getting python3.8. Everywhere I look specifically for how to do it on WSL, they either don't tell me anything different, or they leave pip out.

Here is the main article I was following: [https://www.linuxcapable.com/install-python-3-8-on-ubuntu-linux/#:~:text=Install%20Python%20PIP%20with%203.8%20on%20Ubuntu%20Linux,the%20following%20APT%20command.%20sudo%20apt%20install%20python3-pip](https://www.linuxcapable.com/install-python-3-8-on-ubuntu-linux/#:%7E:text=Install%20Python%20PIP%20with%203.8%20on%20Ubuntu%20Linux,the%20following%20APT%20command.%20sudo%20apt%20install%20python3-pip)

Does anyone know a way to fix this?

EDIT: Here's the error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 32267, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 135, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 111, in bootstrap
    monkeypatch_for_cert(tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 92, in monkeypatch_for_cert
    from pip._internal.commands.install import InstallCommand
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmp4nc0p6x0/pip.zip/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmp4nc0p6x0/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmp4nc0p6x0/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmp4nc0p6x0/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmp4nc0p6x0/pip.zip/pip/_internal/configuration.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmp4nc0p6x0/pip.zip/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmp4nc0p6x0/pip.zip/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 43, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmp4nc0p6x0/pip.zip/pip/_internal/locations/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmp4nc0p6x0/pip.zip/pip/_internal/locations/_distutils.py", line 20, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'
```

Comment: yes, It look like an error Python 3.8 on your WSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here how you could fix your problem and install Python 3.8 for WSL:

go to WSL and your terminal do `sudo apt remove python3.8 python3.8-minimal python3.8-dev python3-pip` then sudo apt install build-essential then we install python

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.8 python3.8-dev
```

then get-pip for your python

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

then pip

```
sudo python3.8 get-pip.py
```

If you are missing the `distutils` here is how to fix it:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install python3.8-distutils

curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

then again:

```
sudo python3.8 get-pip.py
```

Comment: I tried this. It's very close to the procedure I already tried. It gave me the same error as before. I'll add it to my post.

Comment: I edited my post with a solution to your error

Comment: Thanks. I saw a GitHub issue that kind of pointed to that being the issue. I'll try it later today, and if it works, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: I tested your exact procedure, and it installs all the required packages for pip to work. I also found the same thing can also be accomplished by running sudo apt install python3.8-full, which installs much more, but I'm trying to experiment with AI and it seems like I need a million things to make anything work, so if I don't it'll probably complain later about not having things. Besides, drive space isn't an issue, so no point in being stingy with it.

Comment: Having lots of package even the not needed one is not a real problem if you want to experiment, and you can do a fresh install without them later if you want